# PHP's function curl_init() variable as array variable (Solved. Had understood about using an array to curl_curl().)

Tags: php, curl

Here is my code. 
I want to modify the $new_ch for $new_ch[]. Is it viable for curl_init() this function? I want an array with an auto increment for each $new_ch so that I am curious about the array with curl_init() this function. Wish you reply. Thanks.

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$judge = fopen($sourcefile,"r+");
while(!feof($judge))
{
  $destination = fgets($judge);
  $new_ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($new_ch, CURLOPT_URL, $destination);
  curl_setopt($new_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($new_ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($new_ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);
  curl_setopt($new_ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($new_ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent_name);
  curl_setopt($new_ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar);
  $getinner = curl_exec($new_ch);
  $saveinner = fopen('./'.$datetime.'/'.$datetime.'.txt',"w+");
  fwrite($saveinner,$getinner);
  fclose($saveinner);
  $dom_new = file_get_html('./'.$datetime.'/'.$datetime.'.txt');
  foreach($dom_new->find('a') as $dom_new_element)
  {
    $needle_new = $dom_new_element->href;
    $final_target = preg_match("/txt/",$needle_new);
    $final_source = $site_rid.$needle_new."\n";
    $mytrimaddress = parse_url($final_source, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    $eachone = explode("&", $mytrimaddress);
    $trimthename = trim($eachone[5]);
    $lefttrim = ltrim($trimthename, "/");
    $remaintrim = substr($lefttrim, 0, strlen($lefttrim)-1);
    file_put_contents('./'.$datetime.'/'.$remaintrim, $final_source);
  }
  curl_close($new_ch);
  $count++;
  if($count > 5)
  {
  exit;
  } else {
  continue;
  }
}
?>
```

Edit: 
At the past moment, I am not sure this way to do like this. So, I asked the question. Most of the command cases I searched on internet are assigned to a variable instead of an array.

I wish some added votes for those post. I also like to help others' question. But, the current reputation is quite low and I am not able to reply any question. Hope you understand my confession.

Comment: Your question is _very_ unclear and hard to understand.

Comment: Why don't you just try it, and when it doesn't work come back and show is your broken code.

Comment: Hi, 
Where is the blurry section for you to get understood? I would like to modify.

Comment: As with most of these types of questions, my initial answer is: have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: I just want to make sure the variable array for curl_init() this function workable or not.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the variable array for curl_init()"_? `curl_init()` returns a cURL handle on success or false on error. Like others already mentioned, try it and come back if you have some _specific issue_.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why this wouldn't be possible. Just replace your `$new_ch` with an array:

```
$count = 0;
$curl_chs = [];
$judge = fopen($sourcefile,"r+");
while(!feof($judge))
{
  $destination = fgets($judge);
  $curl_chs[$count] = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($curl_chs[$count], CURLOPT_URL, $destination);
  curl_setopt($curl_chs[$count], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
...etc
```

Just make sure you use the same array index for all `curl` functions in that iteration.

Note: I'm using `$count` because it's already a counter that starts at `0` and is incremented on every iteration of your loop.

Comment: Your explanation is brief and touch the point. This real help and breaking-through point to my past unthinking and trying question. Thanks. Wish some votes for reputation rising. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I post the code here.

```
<?php 
$datetime=date(“Ymd”);
$agent_name ='Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G930VC Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36';
$cookie_jar=‘/home/cookiefile.txt;

$judge = fopen($sourcefile,"r+");
while(!feof($judge))
{
  $i=0;
  $new_ch = array();
  $destination = fgets($judge);
  $new_ch[$i] = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($new_ch[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $destination);
  curl_setopt($new_ch[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($new_ch[$i], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($new_ch[$i], CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);
  curl_setopt($new_ch[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($new_ch[$i], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent_name);
  curl_setopt($new_ch[$i], CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar);
  $getinner = curl_exec($new_ch[$i]);
  $saveinner = fopen('./'.$datetime.'/'.$datetime.'.txt',"w+");
  fwrite($saveinner,$getinner);
  fclose($saveinner);
  $dom_new = file_get_html('./'.$datetime.'/'.$datetime.'.txt');
  foreach($dom_new->find('a') as $dom_new_element)
  {
    $needle_new = $dom_new_element->href;
    $final_target = preg_match("/txt/",$needle_new);
    $final_source = $site_rid.$needle_new."\n";
    $mytrimaddress = parse_url($final_source, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    $eachone = explode("&", $mytrimaddress);
    $trimthename = trim($eachone[5]);
    $lefttrim = ltrim($trimthename, "/");
    $remaintrim = substr($lefttrim, 0, strlen($lefttrim)-1);
    file_put_contents('./'.$datetime.'/'.$remaintrim, $final_source);
  }
  }
  $i++;
  sleep(2);
}
?>
```

Edit: Add the `<?php MORE SOMETHING ?>` for completing the code content to readers. I skip the source target for concern. If you are really curious about it, I will post that and please have good votes and comments for this post.