# (PHP) How to arrange HTML table content having breaking row element for outputting as one line output?

Tags: php, web-crawler

I want to arrange a output format from a crawled file.

The output file I want to make them all in one line.

For parting each `td`, my expected output is as below:

```
<b>Nation / Area</b>(Name tag)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Detail</b>Address Telephone
```

> (Explanation) "Nation / Area", "(Name tag)", "4 spaces", "Detail" and
>   "Address Telephone" are sequently listed as my expected output. **Totally there are 5 fields.**

==================================================


I don't know how to handle this case.

This is the page **HTML** code.

```
<table border='1' id='hi_hosts_table_id' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4'>
    <tr>
        <td class='hi_table_header'><b>Nation / Area</b><br>(Name tag)</td>
        <td class='hi_table_header'><b>Detail</b><br>Address<br>Telephone</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my code for arranging that output file.

```
$absolute_path = '/home/hi/mycrawler/benchmark';
include($absolute_path.'/simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php');
$dom = file_get_html($absolute_path.'/'.$datetime.'benchmark.html');
#download the list
if ($dom->find('table[id=hi_hosts_table_id]'))
{
  foreach($dom->find('table[id=hi_hosts_table_id]')->find('tr') as $row) 
    {
      $location = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;
      $detail= $row->find('td',1)->plaintext;
      echo "$location $detail\n";
    }
} else {
  #Pending match or not match 
  echo "No match. There are some problems.\n";
  exit(0);
}
exit(0);
?>
```

Comment: do you just want to use a tab in between $location and $detail??

Comment: If you want to have the output on 1 line, do not use <br> inside your <td></td>.  This will force the output to go to the next line.

Comment: @Nic3500 Thanks. That moment I am stupid on that. Thanks your comment. My reputation is lower. I wish you can vote this post. Thanks your generous help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute `$row->find('td',0)`, the result is a node that described the `<td class='hi_table_header'><b>Nation / Area</b><br>(Name tag</td>` part of the HTML.

When you then do `->plaintext`, the code that gets executed is `simple_html_dom_node::text()`. While this method seems to do a lot of things, it doesn't *transform the HTML into plaintext*; rather, it just returns *all the "text"*.

So, if you want to remove line break, you'll have to do that yourself:

```
$location = str_replace('<br>', ' ', $row->find('td',0)->plaintext);
$detail= str_replace('<br>', ' ', $row->find('td',1)->plaintext);
```

Comment: A derivate matter is here. If the `td` has a code as `<td class='hi_table_row_0' style='text-align: right;'><b><span style='font-size: 10pt;'>Note</span></b><BR>Rate: <b>12 pt</b><BR><BR><b>58 min</b><BR>Period: <BR>2 weeks</td>`, how to get the  `<td class='hi_table_row_0' style='text-align: right;'><b><span style='font-size: 10pt;'>Note</span></b><BR>Rate: <b>12 pt</b><BR><BR><b>58 min</b><BR>` only. The rest of `Period: <BR>2 weeks</td>` section I want to get rid of it. Thanks again.

Comment: Man, you've got messy HTML to work with. I *think* I would split that on the `<br>` tag using `explode()`, remove the last two items from the list with `array_slice()` and then re-combine it with `implode()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. The functions you nominated is good for me to create what I want. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind to add votes to rise this answer? I don't know why my reputation is quite low. Wish you can help.

Comment: @jefferyear "I don't know why my reputation is quite low." Your sentences are very unclean. Also see the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058062/phps-function-curl-init-variable-as-array-variable-solved-had-understood-ab for example. Also, please don't ask for upvotes. People won't upvote a 4 year old question just because you asked them to. If anything, people might actually downvote. Spend the time and effort you just spent asking for upvotes on clearing up the questions instead.

Comment: Who doesn’t have the first time at something? I can’t ask and reply any questions due to the low reputation. So, how can I do effort?